# DIstinct edges in arbor.js

Tags: arbor.js

How do I draw edges that are non-overlapping using arbor.js ? for example, I have 2 nodes A and B in my graph. There is a directed edge from A->B and another one from B->A. How do I display these edges in such a way that they don't overlap ?

Answer (score 0):

well,you have the edge renderer at your disposal, so you can draw an arc-ed line in canvas between the two points...(to do this,use particlesystem.eachedge and see if B and A are connected, then make a arc-ed edge)